# 'Syntax error near unexpected token' error on PHP code sniffer .xml file without a syntax error in it

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpstorm-2017.1

`phpcs` is installed on the system and code sniffing works fine from the command line.

```
phpcs --extensions=php /path/to/code.php`
```

^ works fine.

For the PHP Storm IDE, I've specified the location of the ruleset.xml file in the settings like so:

`Cmd` + `,` > `PHP Code Sniffer validation` > `Coding standard` > `Custom` > Path to ruleset.xml

However, I get this error:

```
PHP Code Sniffer
        phpcs: /Users/gketkar/code-sniffer/Blah/ruleset.xml: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
        /Users/gketkar/code-sniffer/Blah/ruleset.xml: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0"?>'
```

UPDATE:
The ruleset.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Blah">
    <description>Blah Coding Standards</description>
    <rule ref="Generic">
        <exclude name="Generic.Formatting.SpaceAfterCast.NoSpace"/>
        <exclude name="Generic.PHP.DeprecatedFunctions"/>
        <exclude name="Generic.PHP.DisallowShortOpenTag.EchoFound"/>
        <exclude name="Generic.PHP.UpperCaseConstant.Found"/>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Comment: where is the content of the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have the `ruleset.xml` loaded into the setting that should have the `phpcs` binary.  In PHPStorm:

1. Open preferences
2. Navigate to Language & Frameworks > PHP > Code
   Sniffer
3. Click the [...] next to the configuration
4. Validate the path to the phpcs

Make sure that path points to a `phpcs` file and not the `ruleset.xml` file.  If you don't have one, try https://packagist.org/packages/squizlabs/php_codesniffer